# How to create a list, and compare it to another list

Tags: apex

I am writing a batch job, and got stuck. I am trying to create a list 1, and then another list 2, but want to identify only the records in list 2 that match a field in list 1.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. I think I must use a for loop to accomplish what I am looking for:

```
map<id,FEMA_DATA__c> setFemaDataId = new map<id,FEMA_DATA__c>([Select id, FEMA_ID__c From FEMA_DATA__c]);

case[] cafd = [Select id, FEMA_ID__c, AccountId From Case Where FEMA_ID__c = :femadatalist.FEMA_ID__c];
```

Comment: So you're trying to find cases that contain a `FEMA_ID__c` from `FEMA_DATA__c`?

Comment: FEMA_ID__c is a text field that will contain an id. That Id will be passed onto the Case and the FEMA_DATA__c object. I want to find all Cases that have matching FEMA_ID__c  from the FEMA_DATA__c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `FEMA_ID__c` is a lookup field to some third object, you can simply use a subquery here:

```
SELECT Id, FEMA_ID__c, AccountId 
FROM Case
WHERE FEMA_ID__c IN (SELECT FEMA_ID__c FROM FEMA_DATA__c)
```

If `FEMA_ID__c` is not a lookup field but a string or some other type of data point, you can accumulate a `Set` of that type and use it in an `IN` clause. Below, assuming this field is a `String`:

```
Set<String> femaIds = new Set<String>();

for (FEMA_DATA__c fd : [Select id, FEMA_ID__c From FEMA_DATA__c]) {
    femaIds.add(fd.FEMA_ID__c);
}

case[] cafd = [Select id, FEMA_ID__c, AccountId From Case Where FEMA_ID__c IN :femaIds];
```

Comment: Thank you David. Yes FEMA_ID__c is a string field that would hold a unique ID passed from another system. I think this would work. Thank you !!!